# Find and Replace Database Data by Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: database, wordpress, replace, google-sheets

We have a very large Wordpress database with hundreds of posts.

We have a google spreadsheet with thousands of links that need to be replaced with new links. Each link is unique. It's a two column spreadsheet, the first column is the link that needs to be replaced, the second column is the new link. This spreadsheet is thousands of lines, so we're trying to find a way to automate.

Seeing as each link is unique, a regex expression won't do the job. Is there a way to do a find and replace in our database using the spreadsheet as a guide?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: We started trying regex, but with each link being completely unique, it wasn't going to work. At this point we haven't tried anything else, as we don't really know where to start.

Comment: Thanks for the non-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample, basic MySQL query to find/replace used in a database tool like PHPMyAdmin or Adminer is this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');
```

That looks for the exact string of the old URL and replaces it with the new URL, only in the wp_posts table. (You may also need to search `wp_postmeta` and options tables).

You could use text editor tools or the spreadsheet to develop all your changes into a list of UPDATE queries and run them. Since all of the URLs are unique, this may be your only option.

Test a few before you run them all. Backup your database and run the queries on a copy of the site. Running all the queries at once may timeout PHP or MySQL and kill your server.

Probably a good idea to clean the database of Wordpress post revisions first, because if you have hundreds of posts, the query will also process those, and running all the queries at once may timeout and kill the server.

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'revision'
```

Then optimize all tables in the database tool.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Aha, and Sublime Text should be able to help me bring all of these lines in and format them quickly into SQL queries. Thanks a lot, this will save us tons of time!

Comment: Thanks, that should work OK. I've used the technique in the past.